# How do newlines in text files work?

Tags: newlines

When the OS stores a .txt file (for example), how does it denote whitespace or a newline?

If I'm not mistaken, all data is stored on the hard drive in binary. So is there a certain binary sequence that signals a newline? Or is there a character or characters that signal the OS once the file has been read from binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the OS, it uses special characters Linefeed and/or Carriage Return to denote a newline  (DOS uses both, Linux uses just Linefeed, and I think, but am not certain that OSX uses just Carriage return).

The characters associated with Carriage return are 0x0D and Linefeed is 0x0A.

Comment: So do linefeed and carriage return characters get stored at the end of the line's binary code?

Comment: Yes. Each line in a text file ends with the operating system's representation of newline. (CR, LF, or the two-character CRLF sequence.) With the possible exception of the very last line, which in some cases may be terminated by the end of file rather than having this mark.

Comment: OS X uses just Line Feed. Classic Mac OS uses just Carriage Return.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, all data on the hard drive is binary.  Text files are stored in binary as well.  There is no difference between a text file or movie.  Operating systems do know what a text file is and can convert that binary file into human readable form, know as a text file.  Windows and *NIX handle text files a little differently, but more or less the same.  There are characters that denote `end of line`, `Carriage return`, `line feed`, and `End of File`.

This Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) goes into a little more depth.